Higher-dimensional analogue of Erdős-Ulam problem
The Erdős–Ulam problem asks if there exists a dense subset of the plane with all pairwise distances rational. It remains open, although a negative answer would follow from Bombieri–Lang or abc.
What is the status of the analogous question in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\ge 3$? I'm guessing that it is also open, but at first glance, the problem could be settled in some higher dimension without implying anything about two dimensions. I searched a bit but couldn't find any references to the higher-dimensional analogue.
